# Polarizer vs Voltage curve

Tags: optics, polarization

I collected some data from a polarizer experiment. A laser was passed through a polarizer, and the emerging light measured with a photodiode connected to a voltmeter. The polarizer was rotated from -90 to +90 degrees with voltmeter readings recorded and plotted.

Can anyone tell me why the curve looks like this? I'm just not expecting the sharp turnaround at +30 degrees. It should be cosinusoidal (Malus), but it looks like the absolute value of a cosine. Two other polarizers plot the same shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's a square cosine the curve. It's due to Malus law, that applies to completely plane polarized light (you can assume laser light it's like this) hits an polarizer, the intensity $I$ of the light transmitted by the polarized is proportional to the square of the cosine of angle between the angles of polaritzation of light and analyzer. The fact that it doesn't reach $I=0$ may be due to some background light

Comment: Yeah, it's raw data and the background light (0.294 V) is in there. But I expect the square of a cosine to look like .. a cosine, only shifted and scaled.

Comment: And it is. You have $y=A+Bcos(Cx+D)$, where $A,B,C$ and $D$ are constants, what may causes some trouble is D, but you can solve by shifting $x$ origin

Answer (score 1):

If your experiment is really as simple as you say, I agree that the result is rather unexpected. I don't have an answer for you, but I could offer some suggestions to explore.

You mentioned that this is a feature of several polarizers. If you are confident of the quality of the polarizers (for your operating wavelength!), then you can rule out the polarizer acting funny.  They are usually quite reliable and consistent. On the other hand, it is easy to mistake components in an optics lab.

Other possible sources of systematic error I can think off the top of my head:

1. Non-linear input polarization
2. Nonlinear photodiode response
3. Polarization-sensitive detection optics
4. Stray light in detector

First, to rule out (4), or at least quantify it, measure the photovoltage with the laser blocked, but everything else the same.

To rule out (2), find the photodiode paperwork and make sure you're in the right operating conditions (especially input power range). If you're using some home-built thing, you need to think about this carefully.

To rule out (1), read the laser specs. Then, carefully consider each optic between the laser and the polarizer. If your laser is strongly linearly polarized and all you have are mirrors and lenses, you're probably fine in this category.

Finally, (3).  Since your polarizer is rotating, the beam polarization coming into your detection system will be rotating as well. This can be problematic if you have polarization-sensitive optics such as a tilted piece of glass, a dielectric mirror, a beamsplitter, or a grating since then you won't detect all the light that gets through your polarizer equally.

Hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: All good.   #2 especially stands out to me given the small range of voltages and the evidently simple setup:  diode and voltmeter.    Diodes operating in photovoltaic mode are not linear.   Recommendation to the OP:  [A reverse-bias set up](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215116/reverse-biased-photodiode-gain-resistor-selection) is not hard to set up, needing only a battery and a resistor.  Choosing the resistor requires a little thought and knowledge of the laser, but you can start with 10 kOhms and go up or down from there until you get a decent voltage range.